# Pie Chat not showing up in browser I'm using D3 with simple HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have created a simple Pie chat using D3.JS however when i load up my file in chrome or any browser (**index.html**) the pie chat is not loading it is only showing the title.

I'm not sure where i am going wrong for my pie chat not to be presented. any help will be appreciated. Thank you

**style.css** -

```
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

.arc2 text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc2 path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

**pie.js** -

```
// margin
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 500 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    radius = width/2;

// color range
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#BBDEFB", "#90CAF9", "#64B5F6", "#42A5F5", "#2196F3", "#1E88E5", "#1976D2"]);

// pie chart arc. Need to create arcs before generating pie
var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

// donut chart arc
var arc2 = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

// arc for the labels position
var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

// generate pie chart and donut chart
var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

// define the svg for pie chart
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// define the svg donut chart
var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// import data 
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

    // parse data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.count = +d.count;
        d.fruit = d.fruit;
    })

  // "g element is a container used to group other SVG elements"
  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  // append path 
  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.fruit); })
    // transition 
    .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(2000)
      .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

  // append text
  g.append("text")
    .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.fruit; });


    // "g element is a container used to group other SVG elements"
  var g2 = svg2.selectAll(".arc2")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc2");

   // append path 
  g2.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc2)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.fruit); })
    .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(2000)
      .attrTween("d", tweenDonut);

   // append text
  g2.append("text")
    .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.fruit; });

});

// Helper function for animation of pie chart and donut chart
function tweenPie(b) {
  b.innerRadius = 0;
  var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
}

function tweenDonut(b) {
  b.innerRadius = 0;
  var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
  return function(t) { return arc2(i(t)); };
}
```

**CSV file (data.csv)**

```
fruit,count
Apple,10
Strawberry,20
Banana,15
Blueberry,20,
Kiwi,30
Plum,5
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pie Charts</title>

        <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <!-- Load D3 -->
        <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>




    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Pie Chart and Donut Chart</h2>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pie.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pls , make jsfiddle, or insert this code as a snippet

Comment: It is working for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/9w9kQR9RtHIK6QoszbyK?p=preview

Comment: thats so weird, if you download the plnkr and open it up in chrome it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, I'd say that you are not using a server. You cannot load local files without using a server.

Answer (score -1):

That is because **chrome** does not allow **Cross origin requests** to load files except for some protocol requests for that you either need to run it on any **app server(tomcat/jboss etc)** or other browsers such as **Firefox** will be able to run local files with no issues.

Whenever you get any issue I suggest you see the console as it is not necessary there is some error in your code everytime. When you open the html in chrome you can see below issue:

```
d3.v4.min.js:7 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/sidd/Desktop/New%20folder/data.csv. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,       
chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

You can see there is no **`file:///Drive:/`** in the list of protocol that is supported by chrome and hence the issue.